# Does casting a spell with a higher level spell slot change the level of the spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spell-slots, counterspelling

I know that it’s possible to cast spells with a higher level spell slot than what it’s original spell level requires and several spells even give extra benefits for doing so. What I was wondering is if you cast a spell with a higher level spell slot, does the spell become the same level as the spell slot.

For example is someone casts Scorching Ray (a second level spell) with a seventh level spell slot, would the resulting spell be a seventh level spell or a second level spell? I’m curious about this because I want to know how things like counter spell and dispel magic interact with this mechanic.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 5):

### The spell assumes the higher level for that casting

This is explained in the Basic Rules [under the Spellcasting section](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingaSpellataHigherLevel):

> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher level than the spell, the spell assumes the higher level for that casting. For instance, if Umara casts *magic missile* using one of her 2nd-level slots, that *magic missile* is 2nd level.